# How to fix classifer and lambda to TextBlob

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, nlp

any tips are welcome. I have some nlp model and i would like create some classifer.
#test

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
cl.classify("This is an amazing library!")
'pos'
```

But when i add classificator to my lambda , isn't work .

```
df['sentiment_rat'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda tweet: TextBlob(tweet,classifier=cl).sentiment)
```

I get same result like after .sentiment not 'pos' or 'neg'

```
Text    Tweet_tokenized Tweet_nonstop   Tweet_stemmed   sentiment   sentiment_rat
0   0   RT @bennyjohnson:  BOMBSHELL \n\nVeteran &am... [rt, bennyjohnson, bombshell, veteran, amp, bu...   [rt, bennyjohnson, bombshell, veteran, amp, bu...   [rt, bennyjohnson, bombshel, veteran, amp, bus...   (0.0, 0.07142857142857142)  (0.0, 0.07142857142857142)
```

Comment: Unfamiliar with TextBlob, but it might be the probability of the labels ?

Comment: what excatly you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a quick search in [the doc](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/classifiers.html#classifying-textblobs) and by executing it:

`blob.sentiment` is not your classifier, it is the default TextBlob sentiment classifier.

In order to use your classifier you should use `TextBlob(tweet,classifier=cl).classify()` not `TextBlob(tweet,classifier=cl).sentiment`